# Why is my timeToLiveFunction never called?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I have the following flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow workerInfoJmsOut(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, WorkerProperties properties) {
  return IntegrationFlows
    .from(ChannelNames.WORKER_INFO)
    .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
      .timeToLiveFunction(message -> properties.getHeartbeatTtl().toMillis())
      .destination(JmsQueueNames.WORKER_INFO))
    .get();
}
```

And the following gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface DispatcherGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = ChannelNames.WORKER_INFO)
  void submit(WorkerMessage message);
}
```

Which is called every 1s:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void beat() {
  dispatcherGateway.submit(WorkerInfoNotice.of(...));
}
```

However, the breakpoint in the `timeToLiveFunction` is never hit:

[image: location of the breakpoint]

Did I misunderstand something or why is it never hit?

`spring-integration-jms:5.3.1.RELEASE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I need to enable explicit QoS

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow workerInfoJmsOut(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, WorkerProperties properties) {
  return IntegrationFlows
    .from(ChannelNames.WORKER_INFO)
    .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
      .configureJmsTemplate(spec -> spec.explicitQosEnabled(true))
      .timeToLiveFunction(message -> properties.getHeartbeatTtl().toMillis())
      .destination(JmsQueueNames.WORKER_INFO))
    .get();
}
```

Comment: You are right: this option is indeed a part of QoS: `if (this.jmsTemplate instanceof DynamicJmsTemplate && this.jmsTemplate.isExplicitQosEnabled()) {`